# Populate Listview below Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How would I go about populating a ListView directly below a GalleryView based on what is currently selected in the Gallery?

---

Yes I have album art in the gallery and I want the track listing in the ListView under it, but could the ListView change without the users click? I would like it to change to the album currently centrredin the gallery.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So selecting one image in the Gallery results in more than one line in the ListView? Use setOnItemClickListener on the Gallery and use onItemClick to find the selected Gallery item and replace the data of the ListView according to that item.

Comment: Yes I have album art in the gallery and I want the track listing in the ListView under it, but could the ListView change without the users click? I would like it to change to the album currently centrredin the gallery. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add a second question in this thread. Is your first question (on user click) answered? If yes, please mark thread as answered. Then create a new thread for your second question.

Comment: I was just rewording the original question as it was misunderstood.  I'm trying to clarify my original intent.